# Partial class and setting a function property

Tags: typescript, partials

I'm trying to test an Angular Service that requires another Service, and found [their documentation on the subject](https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-with-a-dependency). What I need to do is to use Typescript's `Partial<T>` of my service and that creates the mock for me.

However, the property that I'm trying to use in my partial is a function. Whenever I try to use the function, it always returns `undefined`.

```
export class MyService {
    public string bar = 'bar';

    getType: Observable<MyType> {
        // implementation detail
    }
}
```

My spec file:

```
describe('FooService',
    () => {
        let serviceStub: Partial<MyService>;
        let service: MyService;

        beforeEach(() => {
            serviceStub = {
                bar: 'foo',
                getType: () => {
                    return Observable.create(MyType.Two);
                }
            };

            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                providers: [
                    FooService,
                    {
                        provide: MyService,
                        useValue: serviceStub
                    }
                ]
            });

            myService = TestBed.get(MyService);
        });

        it('when myService getType is called will not be undefined',
            () => {
                const observable = myService.getType();

                // This fails
                expect(observable).not.toBeUndefined();
            });
    });
```

If I put a breakpoint in the test, `myService.getType` (without quotes) is a function like this:

[image: f () { return fn.apply(this, arguments); }]

What am I doing wrong that I'm unable to assign a property? I also tried breaking the assignment on the Partial to a new line outside of the object instantiation. Does `Partial<T>` not allow function assignment? I was unable to find anything in the docs.

Comment: This is probably not your issue, but it looks like `let service` should be `let myService`

Comment: Just a note: You should not be testing your dependency but what your class to test do using mocks/stubs of your dependency service

Comment: @ChristianSantos That's just the name of the property and wouldn't have any effect on anything.

Comment: @distante You're absolutely correct. I didn't include any code for my `FooService` that I would actually be testing because it was irrelevant to the problem that I'm having. When I try and call `MyService.getType` within `FooService`, I'm getting the same behavior that I am inside that one test where the result of the function that I'm assigning is `undefined`.